Why Doesn't Microsoft Graph API Return the First User-Sent Message in a Thread?
The issue I'm facing revolves around the behavior of the Microsoft Graph API when retrieving email messages. Specifically, I've noticed that when I initiate a thread with a message (the user sends the first email in the thread), the API fails to return that very first message in the thread. This behavior seems inconsistent with the expected functionality, as all other messages in the thread are returned correctly. I'm puzzled by why the API overlooks the initial message when it's sent by the user, and I'm seeking insights or solutions to address this discrepancy.
I attempted to use the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve email messages based on specific criteria, including messages sent or received by a particular user within a certain date range. I expected the API to return all messages meeting the specified conditions, including the very first message in threads initiated by the user.
Here's an example of the query I used:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="(to:username@companyname.io OR from:username@companyname.io) AND received>=2023-11-01 AND received<=2023-11-19"&$select=subject,toRecipients,from,ccRecipients

However, the API failed to return the initial user-sent message in such threads, despite returning all other messages correctly. This outcome was unexpected and led to confusion regarding the API's behavior in this particular scenario.
